# DISKPART: Can't delete extended partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I was trying to convert my MBR disk to GPT disk using MBR2GPT. I first checked the partition list using DiskPart, and I saw there were 4 partitions:

```
DISKPART>list partition
Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Primary             49 GB    31 KB
Partition 0    Extended           415 GB    50 GB
Partition 3    Logical            200 GB    50 GB
Partition 4    Logical            215 GB   250 GB
```

I checked the extended partition:

```
DISKPART>detail partition
Partition 0
Type  : 0F
Hidden: No
Active: No
Offset in Bytes: 53801556480

There is no volume associated with this partition.
```

I tried to delete it but it encountered the following error:

```
DISKPART> delete partition

Virtual Disk Service error:
The extended partition is not empty.
```

I tried to format it, but it seems I can't format the extended partition.

Comment: The extended partition is a container that contains the logical partitions. It is not an independent entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete the extended partition because you may only select one
logical partition at a time and this partition contains several.
Thus, you need to delete all the logical partitions first, then delete the
extended partition.

You may do so in Disk Management, or if you prefer in `diskpart`:

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. Run `diskpart` inside
3. Type **list disk**
4. Type **select disk n** (n is the number of the extended partition)
5. Type **list partition**
6. Type **select partition m** (m is the number of any partition)
7. Type **delete partition**
8. Repeat steps 6-7 to delete the rest of the logical partitions,
   followed in the end by the extended partition itself.

Comment: Do I need to backup any data?

Comment: Yes, anytime you manipulate the disk, it's better to be prepared for the worst. Backup your data, and, if possible, take a backup image of the entire disk. The operation itself is pretty safe (except for the extended partition), just in case of a glitch.